# How to configure a kafka broker in one cluster to publish message

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-dotnet

I have two broker and I want to restrict 2nd one with particular messages for particular region.
for example we have multiple region in world to provide our services like china, India
I just wanted to divert specific partner data for India region to broker1 and china region to broker2.
If this possible, I'm looking for solution  need to implement in C#, but welcome ideas.

I have initial configuration like this

```
`"Kafka": {`
    `"Address": "[\"localhost\"]",
`   ` "BrokerHosts": "[\"localhost:9092\"]",`
    `"BrokerHostsIndia": "[\"localhost:9094\"]",`
`}`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure I understand the problem. Your config here is for *clusters*, not brokers.

You can do `var bootstrapIndia = config.get("Kafka").get("BrokerHostsIndia")`, then set that in `ProducerConfig` to get a producer for the "India region" **cluster**.

One producer cannot send to multiple clusters at once, so you need to have some `Dictionary<string, IProducer>`, then create multiple instances per-region.

Or produce to one region, then use tools like MirrorMaker to mirror to another.

Comment: Can you provide some references?

Comment: References to what? Your question is unrelated to Kafka, it's only C# application configuration and variable management